# Permanent line at the bottom of the console window in batch files

Tags: scripting, batch-file, console, statusbar

Just wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to have a permament line of text at the bottom of a cmd prompt window when running a batch file? So it floats, and if there is a lot of text flowing on the screen, and the cmd prompt starts to scroll, that line of text is still there at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Not without external programs. Your output options are limited to:

- Changing the foreground and background color of all text in the console
- Printing a line of text at the current cursor position
- Printing some text (without a trailing line break) at the current cursor position

Without writing your own programs (or resorting to others) you can't do anything else with the console output.

When needing a line or something to display status while the main portion of the output scrolls away I've usually been using the window title for that; you can set it with `title`.